# Does urllib.urlopen() download data lazily?

Tags: python, parsing, image-processing, html-parsing, urllib2

Looking at the reddit python code for choosing an image from a url's html: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L178

In _fetch_image_size, they use urllib2 as if the image bytes are only downloaded after calling response.read(1024).  I searched around a bit to confirm that urllib2 is optimized to lazily download bytes only when read() is called, but I couldn't find much documentation on the return type (httplib.HTTPResponse).  Only that it is a file-like object (so you can call read() on it).

I tested urllib2.urlopen() and it has a little delay for me, but maybe that's just the delay in opening up a socket.  Calling read() on the result is very fast for a somewhat large image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When urllib2.urlopen() is called, it creates a socket and the data is sent from the server to the client. At this point, the socket is at CLOSE-WAIT ([figure 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)). What this means is it is waiting for the client to call close() on the socket, which happens when you use read().

To answer your question, all the data is sent to you regardless of how much you read and it happens prior to read.

Cheers!

Comment: Very interesting, then it appears reddit isn't getting the full performance benefit they imply they're getting in the comment (though they do avoid looping through the rest of the image data.  sidebar - is there any memory benefit like not loading the full image byte data into memory?  my socket knowledge is a little fuzzy).  Do you have any references for this answer where I can read more or are you just intimately familiar with the inner-workings of urllib2?

Comment: I monitored the socket and had it pause at various locations in the process. Everything is already in memory after the initial request in the object returned from urllib2.urlopen(), but if it is duplicated, then it would save the additional memory.